# How does chrome know when a server becomes available?

Tags: google-chrome

Try these steps:

1. Find or create a web server (Apache, Node.js, ...) that you can control
2. Find or create a resource to be served by said web server
3. Shutdown web server
4. Try to access a resource at that server's address in Chrome
5. Notice: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED page is shown
6. Start web server
7. Notice: Chrome *automatically* reloads the request.

I have two questions:

- How does Chrome accomplish this? Is it just repetitively polling the server somehow?
- How could I investigate this myself?

I've tried a few different google searches, but all I can find are support forums for chrome not connecting or pages being unavailable.

Comment: You can run wireshark and discover tcp polling